# Remove sheets from workbook where Remove Sheet option is greyed out

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has 2 worksheets, Sheet1 & Sheet12.

This workbook also has many "Sheet" items, Sheet1, Sheet11, Sheet111. I have no idea how they got there. When I right-click over one the Remove Sheet is grayed out.

[image: Project Explorer ScreenShot]

Comment: Did someone prepare this workbook for you?  Or develop any tools in it?  Sometimes the existence of hidden worksheets means that someone hid them to prevent inadvertent tempering.  That is, if you remove them something may not work anymore.

Comment: Pay attentions to icons of sheets - only Sheet15 and Sheet16 have correct icon. Moreover, there can be no more than on `ThisWorkbook` modules. Something is really messed up here...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the sheets are hidden or "very-hidden" (i.e. only visible to VBA).

You can check the "Visible" property of each worksheet in worksheet "Properties".

It can have values xlSheetVisible = -1, xlSheetHidden = 0 or xlSheetVeryHidden = 2.

You can change the "Visible" property to make them visible, then delete them manually, or do the deletion using VBA.